# Looking for text in a range with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range that contains different words in different columns the range would be DT21:EH400.  I want to know if there is a way to search through that range and if there is a word copy and paste it to the same row it is on but in column B.

Comment: yes it is posible. is that what you need?

Comment: yes I am looking for code in vba that would do that.

Comment: Look midway down the right side of this page for the *Related* questions that SO has determined closely approximate a solution to your question. There is at least one link there that seems to answer your question. If you TRY to use the answer there to answer your question but run into trouble, edit your post here to show what you have TRIED and we would be happy to offer assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The built in Find functionality should be quicker than writing your own loop:

```
Sub findUsingFIND()

    Dim searchString As String
    searchString = Excel.Application.InputBox("Enter string please")

    Dim targetArea As Range
    Set targetArea = Excel.Application.InputBox("Select range to search", , , , , , , 8)

    targetArea.Select
    'Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("DT21:EH400").Select

    Dim foundRange As Range
    With targetArea
        Set foundRange = _
            .Find(What:=searchString, _
                  After:=.Cells(1), _
                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & foundRange.Row) = searchString 
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If

End Sub
```

If there are several instances of the string then the above can be adapted to the following:

```
Sub findSeveralUsingFIND()

    Dim searchString As String
    searchString = Excel.Application.InputBox("Enter string please")

    Dim targetArea As Range
    Set targetArea = Excel.Application.InputBox("Select range to search", , , , , , , 8)

    targetArea.Select
    'Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("DT21:EH400").Select

    Dim foundRange As Range
    With targetArea
        Set foundRange = _
            .Find(What:=searchString, _
                  After:=.Cells(1), _
                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False)

        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = foundRange.Address
            Do
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & foundRange.Row).Value = searchString
                Set foundRange = .FindNext(foundRange)
            Loop While Not foundRange Is Nothing And foundRange.Address <> FirstAddress
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

As @ChrisNeilsen points out there is a very fast method that would be preferable if you need to perform your search many times. This uses arrays. My understanding is relatively shallow as to why this approach is quick but I believe it is in connection with the way arrays store the data in a block of memory addresses that are next to each other. Here is a good comparison of different approaches:

http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Here is the macro using an array of variant type:

```
Sub findUsingVARARRAY()

    Dim vArr As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim n As Long

    Dim searchString As String
    searchString = Excel.Application.InputBox("Enter string please")

    Dim targetArea As Range
    Set targetArea = _
      Excel.Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select range to search", Type:=8)

    Dim firstRow As Long

    vArr = targetArea.Value2
    ReDim vRes(LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1)
    For c = LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2)
        ' use vbTextCompare for case insenstitive comapre
        ' use vbBinaryCompare for case senstitive comapre
        If StrComp(vArr(r, c), searchString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            vRes(r, 1) = searchString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c, r

    targetArea.EntireRow.Columns(2) = vRes
End Sub
```

Comment: Be carefull what you assume.  A well structured `Variant Array` loop can be much faster even than a `Find` method (depending on the data)

Comment: @chrisneilsen upped your comment - totally agree and I'll edit my answer. Strangely enough I remembered this this morning.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I've edited my attempt. I'm guessing the user doesn't work with ranges that are so large that it is necessary to work with arrays. I don't use arrays much so please feel free to help me out if I'm not getting as much performance gain from them as is possible.

Comment: I've take the liberty of editing your array code to correct a few issues and provide some optimisation.  If you don't like it feel free to roll back.

Comment: upped comment - appreciated Chris. I will need to deconstruct your changes and think about it, as I don't get to play around with this area of vba nearly enough.

Answer (score -1):

The following code may work

It searches for the word in the range and sets the search word as a value in column B of the row where the search word was found

```
Dim strSearch as String
Dim rngData as Range
Dim rngCell as Range

strSearch = "Word to Search"
Set rngData = Range(Cells(21,124),Cells(400,138))

For each rngCell in rngData
    If rngCell.value = strSearch Then
        cells(rngcell.Row, 2).Value = strSearch
    End if
Next rngCell
```

Comment: If you are going to examine each cell and concatenation to `Cells(<row>, 2)` is not required on multiple matches, a row-by-row search might be more efficient. e.g. `if not iserror(application.match(strSearch, cells(rw, 124).resize(1, 15), 0)) then cells(rw, 2) = strSearch`

Comment: Jeeped, I agree.  Finding a single match is a much more efficient approach rather than looping through each cell.